# Bluetooth doesn't work in a Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bluetooth, 20.04, macbook-pro

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 in Macbook Pro (2012 Edition).
I tried to find additional proprietary drivers, but couldn't. 
How can I get bluetooth working in Ubuntu 20.04 ?

lspci -knn

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller [8086:0154] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller [106b:00fa]
    Kernel driver in use: ivb_uncore
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port [8086:0151] (rev 09)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [106b:00fa]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:1e31] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1e3a] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1e10] (rev c4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1e12] (rev c4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:1e14] (rev c4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1e26] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller [8086:1e57] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:1e03] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1e22] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b4] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b4]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
    Kernel modules: tg3
01:00.1 SD Host controller [0805]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM57765/57785 SDXC/MMC Card Reader [14e4:16bc] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM57765/57785 SDXC/MMC Card Reader [14e4:0000]
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
    Kernel modules: sdhci_pci
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:00f5]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
03:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: LSI Corporation FW643 [TrueFire] PCIe 1394b Controller [11c1:5901] (rev 08)
    Subsystem: LSI Corporation FW643 [TrueFire] PCIe 1394b Controller [11c1:5900]
    Kernel driver in use: firewire_ohci
    Kernel modules: firewire_ohci
04:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation CV82524 Thunderbolt Controller [Light Ridge 4C 2010] [8086:1513]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
05:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation CV82524 Thunderbolt Controller [Light Ridge 4C 2010] [8086:1513]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
05:03.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation CV82524 Thunderbolt Controller [Light Ridge 4C 2010] [8086:1513]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
05:04.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation CV82524 Thunderbolt Controller [Light Ridge 4C 2010] [8086:1513]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
05:05.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation CV82524 Thunderbolt Controller [Light Ridge 4C 2010] [8086:1513]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
05:06.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation CV82524 Thunderbolt Controller [Light Ridge 4C 2010] [8086:1513]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
06:00.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation CV82524 Thunderbolt Controller [Light Ridge 4C 2010] [8086:1513]
    Subsystem: Device [2222:1111]
    Kernel driver in use: thunderbolt
    Kernel modules: thunderbolt
```

dmesg | grep Blue

```
[    2.506330] usb 2-1.8.1.3: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[   16.657094] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   16.657112] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   16.657115] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   16.657116] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   16.657118] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   17.191592] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 63 build 1818
[   17.192580] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: product 05ac:821d
[   17.193565] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x07
[   17.209570] Bluetooth: hci0: eduf-MacBookPro
[   32.181199] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   32.181201] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   32.181205] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   50.307259] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   50.307268] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   50.307277] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b4] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b4]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
    Kernel modules: tg3
--
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:00f5]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 05ac:0252 Apple, Inc. Internal Keyboard/Trackpad (ANSI)
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 05ac:8242 Apple, Inc. Built-in IR Receiver
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 05ac:821d Apple, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0424:2513 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) 2.0 Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:8509 Apple, Inc. FaceTime HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb' dmesg | grep -i blue` terminal command.

Comment: There are a lot of Broadcom bluetooth firmwares [here](https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/tree/master/brcm) . But I cannot find anything for your Broadcom BCM2046 device. Maybe it's a little outdated. But if you found it somewhere , you can put it in the " /lib/firmware/brcm" directory .

Comment: Bluetooth problems might be caused by a missing firmware . And I think there's not any problem concerning the drivers. I had a similar problem with my Broadcom bluetooth device and I downloaded the firmware manually and it worked.